# не понятно как работает мой цикл

Tags: python

хочу на выходе получить `0 20 40 60 40 20 0 20 40 60`
мой чудо код
вход угол который я хочу поделить с интервалом

```
def divider_angle(self,basic_angle):
    # divide angle  with interval and make sequense
    # self.keys_finder()
    some_execute = []
    min_interval = 0.2
    interval_servo = 0.6
    interval_div = interval_servo/min_interval
    div_angle = basic_angle/interval_div
    plus = basic_angle/interval_div
    for _ in range(self.key):
        if div_angle >= basic_angle :
            div_angle -= count
            print(count)
        else:
            div_angle += round(plus)
            count = div_angle
            print(div_angle)
        some_execute.append(div_angle)
    return some_execute
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: получаю [40.0, 60.0, 0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 0.0]

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте в вопрос что даете на входе, что получаете на выходе

Comment: Пробовал пробежаться по элементам some_execute используя функцию int()?)

Comment: Исправьте код, чтобы его можно было просто скопировать и запустить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def divider_angle(basic_angle):
    min_interval = 0.2
    interval_servo = 0.6

    interval_div = int((interval_servo * 10) / (min_interval * 10))

    div_angle = 0
    interval = round(basic_angle / interval_div)

    some_execute = [div_angle]

    for _ in range(9):
        if div_angle >= basic_angle:
            interval *= -1
        div_angle += interval
        if div_angle <= 0:
            interval *= -1
        some_execute.append(div_angle)

    return some_execute

print(divider_angle(60))  # [0, 20, 40, 60, 40, 20, 0, 20, 40, 60]
```

**UPD**

```
def divider_angle(basic_angle):
    min_interval = 0.2
    interval_servo = 0.6

    interval_div = int((interval_servo * 10) / (min_interval * 10))

    div_angle = 0
    interval = round(basic_angle / interval_div)

    some_execute = [div_angle]

    for _ in range(10):
        div_angle += interval

        if div_angle > basic_angle:
            interval *= -1
            div_angle += interval
            continue

        if div_angle < 0:
            interval *= -1
            div_angle += interval
            continue

        some_execute.append(div_angle)

    return some_execute

print(divider_angle(196))  # [0, 65, 130, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195]
```

Comment: есть моменты у кода если не кратные значения вываливается сверху еще одна итерация

Comment: пример можно что на вход и что в результате?

Comment: [0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260, 195, 130, 65, 0, 65, 130, 195, 260]

Comment: на вход divider_angle(196)

Comment: или divider_angle(199)

Comment: [0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264, 198, 132, 66, 0, 66, 132, 198, 264]

Comment: @ЕвгенийПриз обновил ответ

Comment: если на вход подаю 95 пропускает итерацию  [0, 32, 64, 32, 0, 32, 64, 32]

Comment: @ЕвгенийПриз `[0, 31, 62, 93, 62, 31, 0]` - такой вывод должен быть? если да, то вместо округления можно просто брать целую часть `interval = int(basic_angle / interval_div)`

Comment: можно подробнее не очень понятно

Comment: `int(95 / 3) = 31` и `round(95 / 3) = 32`

Comment: буду пробывать отпишусь позже!зарание невороятное спасибо за помощь в решении такой нетривиальной задачи